# How do i apply mean value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f ∈\mathcal{C}[a,b]$ be diﬀerentiable in $]a,b[$. If $f(a) =f(b) = 0$, then, for any real number $α$, there exists $x ∈]a,b[ $such
>   that $f'(x) + αf(x) = 0$.

Let $g(\chi)=f(\chi)+\alpha\int_{0}^{\chi}f'(t)dt$, then planned to apply Rolle's theorem. I couldn't apply Rolle's Theorem. $g(a)\ne g(b).$Can you please tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Well...your title suggests an approach: apply the MVT.

Comment: How? Am I take a Right choice for $g$ ?

Comment: Y'know, figuring out what's a good thing to which you should apply Rolle's or the MVT is what problems like this are *about*.  I assume you didn't just make up that choice of $g$, although offhand I don't see why it would be a good one. When you applied MVT to it, did it tell you anything? If not, maybe there's a better choice out there somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: apply Rolle's theorem to 
$$
g(x)=e^{\alpha x}f(x).
$$

Comment: I have thought in a wrong way. thank you for the correction.